# meaning of $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)\ne L$

Tags: limits, notation

If I want to write the negation of $\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=L$, 
is it considered incorrect to write $\lim_{x\to c}f(x) \ne L$ (because this indicates that the limit exists)?

Comment: I would say that it is indeed incorrect.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation would be that for any sequence $\{x_n\}$ converging to $c$, we have that the sequence $\{f(x_n)\}$ does not converge to $L$.

If $\lim_{x \to c} f(x)$ does not exist, then the statement
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to c} f(x) \neq L
\end{align*}
has no meaning.